# Issues with Kivy on Raspberry Pi 3 with 3.5 in Touchscreen

Tags: python, touchscreen

I followed every guide I could find on installing Kivy to Raspberry Pi.

My touchscreen works totally fine.

Trying to launch various Kivy demos will result in what seems to be a partial launch, but then it will just hang.... maybe my config.ini is not correctly configured?

For example, running 'python main.py' for examples/demo/pictures/:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-04-25_12.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26)
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Broadcom>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <VideoCore IV HW>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range position X is 0 - 4095
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range position Y is 0 - 4095
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range touch major is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range touch minor is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> axes invertion: X is 0, Y is 0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> rotation set to 0
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <ADS7846 Touchscreen>
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <ADS7846 Touchscreen> range ABS X position is 0 -     4095
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <ADS7846 Touchscreen> range ABS Y position is 0 - 4095
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <ADS7846 Touchscreen> range ABS pressure is 0 - 65535
```

And then it just hangs forever. No window pops up, nothing.

Same thing happens running from the touchscreen, running through SSH, and running through tightvncserver remote desktop.

Comment: What if you plug an HDMI monitor? I guess it will properly render the kivy UI on it (at least in my Rpi2 and 3 it does with a default installation). Also check (if you haven't already) some references to using kivy with the pi touchscreen here https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/the-eagerly-awaited-raspberry-pi-display/

Answer (score 0):

Try this<sup>[1]</sup>: edit ~/.kivy/config.ini<sup>[2]</sup> file and replace all the lines under the `[input]` heading with these:

```
mouse = mouse
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

---

**Notes**

<sup>[1]</sup> Reference: https://github.com/mrichardson23/rpi-kivy-screen

<sup>[2]</sup> If you don't have a config.ini just run an example:

```
python ~/kivy/examples/demo/pictures/main.py
```

and it will get created.